# ActionbarSherlock, when run error raises "Android projects library can not be launched"

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My own project uses:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

To implement action bar, I uses [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library. I imported the **sherlock** library into my Eclipse as an existing project. For sherlock, the target platform is **Android v3.2 API 13** .

Then, I added **sherlock** as a library project to my own project. I saw there is Library projects under my own project. Everything seem goes well.

BUT, there is a **red exclamation mark** on my project icon in Eclipse. When I run my project as Android app, Eclipse pop up an alert "**Android library projects cannot be launched.**"

I have no idea where is wrong, since I didn't see any error on eclipse console.

Answer (score 3):

You need to uncheck the box "is library" on the screen where you added ActioonBarSherlock as library.

[image]